# How do you search an undefined string in cmd?

Tags: batch-file

Apologizes for being unclear, i'm new to coding and horrible at explaining but here goes;
Using batch, is there a way to search up (on google) an undefined phrase, eg. I type "search-gorilla" and it opens a google search page on gorillas. 
Thanks in advance, hopefully it was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to call URLs from a batch file using the `start` command. A script for opening a Google search page would look something like this:

```
set /p query="Search string: "
start https://google.com/search?q=%query%
```

This will prompt for a keyword, store it in the variable named `query` and launch Google in the default browser.

Comment: Possible improvement: replace spaces with %20, quotes with... [etc]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just write a script and pass query as an argument and save it with the name search so:

```
@start https://google.com/search?q=%1
```

for example I have the script on my desktop when I call it:

```
%DESKTOP%\search gorilla
```

and you have it.

p.s:
I have an environmental variable called desktop which has the path of the desktop.